# Finding how Many time the letter "x" is appear in the sentence using for loop,break,and continue

Tags: javascript, for-loop, break, continue

I just returning my self to JAVASCRIPT after not coding for serval years
and trying to refresh my memory on how to use "FOR", "BREAK", "CONTINUE" the loop.

What I trying to achieve is to find how many times a specific letter is appearing in the sentence and console.log it, so basically

**1.** I created a new variable "**mywords**" that contains my sentence

```
var mywords="this is the for loop wiTh break and continue.".toLowerCase();
```

**2.** than a variable "**myletter**" than containing the value of what letter to look for

```
var myletter ='t';
```

**3.** and a variable "**howmanytime"** that counting how many time the letter appears in the sentence

```
var howmanytime = 0;
```

**4.** next I created a for loop that counting the length  of the sentence,  keeps looping and adding + 1 to "**howmanytime**" using **i++** until **i** is equal to the sentence length

```
for (var i=0; i <= mywords.length;i++){
if (mywords[i]===myletter){
    howmanytime ++;
}
```

*so now **howmanytime** holding a value 4 and I know that the letter t is appearing 4 times in the sentence

**5.** next I created if statement inside my for loop that checking if the letter appears more than 4 times or less in case it's appearing more than 4 times display in console.log the number that the letter appearing in the sentence + **"more than 3"** and if so than **break** the loop in case it's less than 4 than display only **"less than 3"**

```
if (howmanytime >= 4) {
console.log('more than 3');
console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the senetnce');    
break;    

}else if (howmanytime <=4 ){    

console.log('less than 3');
continue;
 }
```

**now the problem:**
I can't figurate out why when a letter is less than 4 times for example "e" it's displayed 
in a console log **"less than  3 times"** without any other text which is what I want

[image]

but when it's more than 4 times lets go back to letter "t" it's displaying 
"more than 3" and "less than 3"

[image]

**why the "less than 3" is appearing as well?**

**My full code**

```js
var mywords = "this is the for loop wiTh break and continue.".toLowerCase();

var howmanytime = 0;
var myletter = 'e';

for (var i = 0; i <= mywords.length; i++) {
  if (mywords[i] === myletter) {
    howmanytime++;
  }

  if (howmanytime >= 4) {
    console.log('more than 3');
    console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the senetnce');
    break;
  } else if (howmanytime <= 4) {
    console.log('less than 3');
    continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output in case of letter `"e"`?

Comment: do you want to get an information for every letter or for every found letter or at the end with a summary?

Comment: Why do you need to use `break` and `continue`? The `if (howmanytime >= 4)...` should be after the loop. Why do you want to check `howmanytime ` more than once?

Comment: I count the `e` 3 times here: `this is thE for loop wiTh brEak and continuE`. You're checking to see if it's greater than or equal to 4 first.

Comment: I try only to refresh my memory how to use a break and continue in a loop in case the letter is less than 4 times or equal than display a message: "the letter X is appearing X times in the sentence"  + "more than 4" if less than only display the message "less than 4"

Comment: It should be `howmanytime < 4` OR `howmanytime <= 3` for your else if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can't figurate out why when a letter is less than 4 times for example `"e"` it's displayed in a console log `"less than 3 times"` without any other text which is what I want

Because the other text you are displaying inside the `if` block `if (howmanytime >= 4)`. For the letter `"e"` it never gets true so the other text is not logged.

> but when it's more than 4 times lets go back to letter `"t"` it's displaying "more than 3" and `"less than 3"`  why the `"less than 3"` is appearing as well?

Because the initially `howmanytime` is `0` goes on increasing as the letter `"t"` appears in string. Its not `4` or more than `4` in the start of loop.

If you want to display that all in the end just move if statements out of loop body.

```js
var mywords = "this is the for loop wiTh break and continue.".toLowerCase();

var howmanytime = 0;
var myletter = 'e';

for (var i = 0; i <= mywords.length; i++) {
  if (mywords[i] === myletter) {
    howmanytime++;
    if(howmanytime >= 4) break;
  }  
}

if (howmanytime >= 4) {
    console.log('more than 3');
  }
  
else if (howmanytime <= 4) {
    console.log('less than 3');
  }
console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the senetnce');
```

Comment: this is what I did at first but as I said I trying to remember how to use a break and continue, can you give a semilar answer but using break and continue?

Comment: @M.mik Sorry. I really can't understand your question. Can you please tell me how much time you want to log. in case of `e` and `t` and what you wanna log.

Comment: only once for both cases

Comment: @M.mik If only **once** for both cases. Then there is no need to use `console.log` inside loop body. Just use it outside as I did. You can use `break;` if  `howmanytime` becomes equal to or greater than `4`. It will prevent further looping after `4`. And there is no need to `continue;` All the loop body is executed it automatically `continue;`

Comment: indeed logic on your side that's made sense :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could swap the condtions and omit `else` part by using `continue` for the first part and a break for the second condition.

```js
var mywords = "this is the for loop wiTh break and continueeee.".toLowerCase(),
    howmanytime = 0,
    myletter = 'e',
    i;

for (i = 0; i < mywords.length; i++) { // go only until smaller length,
    if (mywords[i] === myletter) {     // the last is length - 1
        howmanytime++;
        if (howmanytime < 3) {
            console.log('less than 3');
            continue;
        }
        if (howmanytime >= 4) {
            console.log('more than 3');
            console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the sentence');
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more useful version of the code which indicates what's happening

```js
var mywords = "this is the for loop wiTh break and continue.".toLowerCase();

var howmanytime = 0;
var myletter = 't';

for (var i = 0; i <= mywords.length; i++) {
  if (mywords[i] === myletter) {
    howmanytime++;
    console.log('Found ' + howmanytime + ' times the letter ' + myletter);
  }

  if (howmanytime >= 4) {
    console.log('more than 3');
    console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the sentence');
    break;
  }
}

/* NOTE! Outside of the loop */
if (howmanytime < 4) {
    console.log('less than 3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`howmanytime >= 4` will be `true` for the set `[4,5,6,7,8,9...]`

`howmanytime <= 4` will be `true` for the set `[4,3,2,1,0,-1...]`

If you want to see if `howmanytime` is atleast `3` you should do `howmanytime >= 3` and the `else` should be `howmanytime < 3`

Please check the interactive example below:

```js
function checkLetter(mywords, myletter) {
  var howmanytime = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= mywords.length; i++) {
    if (mywords[i] === myletter) {
      howmanytime++;
    }

    if (howmanytime >= 3) {
      break;
    } else if (howmanytime < 3) {
      continue;
    }
  }

  if (howmanytime >= 3) {
    console.log('more than 3');
    console.log('the letter ' + myletter.toUpperCase() + ' appearing ' + howmanytime + ' times in the senetnce');
  } else {
    console.log('less than 3');
  }
}

var mywords = "this is the for loop wiTh break and continue.".toLowerCase();

document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach(function(dom) {
  dom.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.clear();
    checkLetter(mywords, dom.getAttribute("letter"));
  });
});
```

```html
<button letter="a">Check 'A'</button>
<button letter="e">Check 'E'</button>
<button letter="t">Check 'T'</button>
```

Some notes:

- The naming convention for JavaScript is `camel-case` which means you should name variable like `myWords` instead of `mywords`.
- The `else if (howmanytime < 3)` part is unnecessary. A simple `else` would do the same task in this case.